# PSQLException: ОШИБКА "data": отношение уже существует

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

Всем привет. использую Spring Boot
При старте возникает такая ошибка
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: отношение "data" уже существует

Класс с моей сущностью

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table
public class Data implements Serializable
{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
  @Column(name = "data_id")
  private UUID id;
  @Column(name = "data_description")
  private String description;

  public Data(UUID id, String description) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
  }
}
```

когда запускаю первый раз, такой ошибки конечно нет. а вот когда далее запускаю возникает.